# How to use referenced DS OSGi services directly after they were set?

Tags: java, osgi

I started with OSGi a few weeks ago and have a question about DS.

Lets say i have 2 bundles, Bundle A and Bundle B. Both register a service via DS / BND Annotations.

Bundle A has a reference to the service of bundle B, and the required set and unset functions implemented.

```
@Reference(dynamic = true, optional = true)
    void setConnector(IDataBaseConnect connector) {
    this.connector = connector;
    doSomeStuff();
    sysout("Connector SET");  <---- NOT called when doSomeStuff runs into an error

}
```

This will never be called when doSomeStuff() runs into an error

```
void unsetConnector(IDataBaseConnect connector){
   this.connector = null
}
```

As u can see, i want to have the reference dynamic and optional, but, if the connector service gets available, i want to do some stuff in the bundle A.

In my case Bundle B has some basic database functionality. Bundle A uses this to read some data from a database and caches it in some java objects. This data will be used by other services.

But, i have a problem with this approach. If my Database service reference is set to Bundle A, I start my database operations in the setConnector function. As long as everything goes smoth i dont have a problem. The reference is set, data gets red, everything is fine. But if the DB-Service runs into an Exception (yes its caught and handled), DS seems to "forget" about the set Reference, and it will never be removed, when i stop the service.

I guess i should not call any functions in the setConnector function, but if so, how would i implement a method that is only called if the new reference is set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic and optional references should be used in very rare cases. I neither have used dynamic nor optional references till now although I implemented quite a few components. In case of database connections there other issues, too:

- What if IDatabaseConnect reference is replaced between running two SQL statements?
- What if separate functions were visited by callers, the IDatabaseConnect is replaced but the global transaction is the same?

I suggest that you should use a non-dynamic, non-optional reference and put the *doSomeStuff()* logic into your activate method. In that case you can be sure that the reference is available when your business logic runs.

Answer (score 1):

If `doSomeStuff()` throws an exception which is then propagated out of the bind method `setConnector`, DS will assume your bind method is broken and that your component failed to accept the bound service. DS will then consider the service to not be bound to the component, so the unbind method for the service wont be called.

You need to handle any exception from `doSomeStuff()` in your bind method. For example:

```
@Reference(dynamic = true, optional = true)
void setConnector(IDataBaseConnect connector) {
  this.connector = connector;
  try {
    doSomeStuff();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     // handle e but don't let it propagate out of this bind method
  }
  sysout("Connector SET");
}
```